# Scales, Theory and memorization

Tags: theory, scales

When you're learning a scale pattern. I.e Harmonic minor, Hungarian minor, ect do you have to learn a variation of every note? A-G.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is actually 'When learning a scale pattern, do you have to learn it in all keys', then, eventually, yes. It makes sense, as you don't know now what key you may need to be playing in, in the future. How that's achieved is instrument dependent. On guitar, each key may only involve moving the shape up or down the fretboard. On others, it means learning a separate pattern of notes for each key.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways of learning and remembering scales. Depending on how you think of scales, you may or may not need to remember them differently for each scale degree.

Personally, I don't think of scales differently depending on what root note they're based on. I just think of the abstract 'shape' of the scale as a pattern of intervals, and then I mentally map that onto the layout of whatever instrument I'm playing.

Comment: How does that work for keyboards? Great for guitar/bass.

Comment: @Tim as long as have the picture in my mind of where each chromatic interval is from any given root note, I can play any scale based on that root note, because I essentially think of every scale as a subset of the chromatic.

Comment: @topo morto, I would add in my own case, "Or by the sound."  I find it much easier to learn a scale by listening to the intervals than by memorizing the interval sizes and playing accordingly.